# How can I copy music to my iPod nano without iTunes on Mac?

Tags: mac, itunes, ipod

Title says it all. I'm on Mac with the latest iTunes and it doesn't recognize my iPod anymore although it mounts to the desktop. I tried all and everything but it doesn't work (the iPod works on other Macs though, it itself is fine).

How can I copy my music to the iPod without going through iTunes? Are there any tools like on Windows for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to clear things up, would you at all be interested in diagnosing why your iPod will not work with iTunes or are you strictly looking for a solution to load music onto the iPod without iTunes?

Answer (score 2):

www.getsongbird.com  from mozilla I think has ipod support now. It's free also.

http://www.yamipod.com is another good cross platform app.

Comment: Well YamlPod didn't work. Gotta try Songbird now.

Comment: you may need to restore your ipod http://www.apple.com/support/ipod/five_rs/nano3gen/